# Get first iframe from string

Tags: javascript

I get content from : `json.feed.entry[i].content.$t`

It means I have string  : `var content = json.feed.entry[i].content.$t ;`

The content is post format.

How can I get the first `<iframe>...</iframe>` from above content.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

### DO NOT USE REGEX! USE DOM

...Not that you can't do that with regex, but *"just because you can, doesn't mean you should!"*.

You can use the inbuilt dom tools to do this :) See below.

```js
var myString = "Your content <iframe>Don't use regex</iframe> more content <iframe>Another div</iframe>";

var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.innerHTML = myString;
console.log(newDiv.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].outerHTML); //your first iframe!
```

This is a simple demonstration. But you can employ the same technique at many places :)

Comment: I'll comment here too - you know nothing about the content of string and where it comes from. he has a string with some tags, he can put this string into node, it will be parsed and converted by browser. But what if this string is not valid html code? what if iframe will load the src and do something else and he does not want it??

Comment: Sorry, but it is 2 AM and I do not strength and time to discuss it.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to use regular expressions to get all the iframes in that string.
2. Then get the code for the first one.

There is a in-build function is PHP (preg_match_all). If nothing works you can send the content to backend (AJAX call) and process it in the backend).

Comment: Assuming the OP is using PHP for the back-end.